Bit-wise MAP criterion for Bi-AWGN Channel
I am trying to derive an expression for the bit-wise MAP criterion for the binary AWGN channel.
I were able to derive the codeword ML criterion, but now using the LLRs obtained from the codeword ML criterion, I would like to find the bit-wise LLRs or probabilities.
I am aware this should be possible by marginalisation, but my math does not add up in the end.
I start with,
$$ p(y_i|x_i) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi \sigma^2)}} \textrm{exp}\left[ - \frac{(y_i - x_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]
$$
and then this results in,
$$
p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} p(y_i | x_i).
$$
where $x_i \in \{-1, 1 \}$.
Using this I can find easily the probabilities per codeword in the codebook.
But how now to proceed to find the probabilities per bit?
$$
b_{i, est} = \arg \max_{b_i  \in \{0, 1\}} p(\mathbf{y} | b_i)
$$
But how can I plug in here the codeword probabilities?
You marginalize like this right?
$$
p(\mathbf{y}|x_i)= \sum_{\mathbf{x}_j: x_j^i = 0} p(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}_j)p(\mathbf{x}_j)
$$
